# Validating Error with submit button

Tags: templates, validation

I really need your help.. I am tryin like 3 days now to change the first pic and make it like the 3rd one. I did it but when Iremove depoarture day the enquire button doesnt work and dont get the form(2nd pic).

I tottaly remoce the calendar cause i couldnt pass the validate. What am I doin wrong? Can you please help me?

I am leaving the php codes like it was and how i made it. Please any feedback would be helpful..

Thnak you in advance.

[image]

[image]

This the code in php files... That was ready by a guy but I cant find him and let me know what he done. So I am asking you for help guys please take a look.

PS. All the code in comments is what I delete to disappear the calendar that gave me the error.

```
 <?php

 //check is booking with modal
 $st_is_booking_modal = apply_filters('st_is_booking_modal',false);

 $type_tour = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'type_tour',true);

  echo STTemplate::message();
 ?>
  <?php 

 // $tour_show_calendar = st()->get_option('tour_show_calendar', 'on');
 // $tour_show_calendar_below = st()->get_option('tour_show_calendar_below', 'off');
  // if($tour_show_calendar == 'on' && $tour_show_calendar_below == 'off'):
?>
 <div class='tour_show_caledar_below_off'>
<?php // echo st()->load_template('tours/elements/tour_calendar'); ?>
</div>
 <?php // endif; ?>
 <div class="package-info-wrapper" style="width: 100%">
 <div class="overlay-form"><i class="fa fa-refresh text-color"></i></div>
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="package-info">
            <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
            <span class="head"><?php _e('Cruise Type',ST_TEXTDOMAIN) ?>: </span>
            <span><?php if($type_tour == 'daily_tour') echo __('Daily Cruise', ST_TEXTDOMAIN); else echo __('Fixed Date', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) ?></span>
        </div>    
        <?php if($type_tour == 'daily_tour'){ ?>
            <div class="package-info">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <span class="head"><?php _e('Duration',ST_TEXTDOMAIN) ?>: </span>
                <?php
                echo STTour::get_duration_unit();                   

                ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="package-info">
            <?php $max_people = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'max_people', true) ?>
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <span class="head"><?php st_the_language('tour_max_people') ?>: </span>
            <?php 
                if( !$max_people || $max_people == 0 ){
                    $max_people = __('Unlimited', ST_TEXTDOMAIN);
                }
                echo esc_html($max_people) 
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="package-info">
            <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
            <span class="head"><?php st_the_language('tour_location') ?>: </span>
            <?php echo TravelHelper::locationHtml(get_the_ID()); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="package-info pull-left">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <span class="head"><?php st_the_language('tour_rate') ?>:</span>
            </div>
            <div  class="pull-left pl-5">
                <ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
                    <?php
                    $avg = STReview::get_avg_rate();
                    echo TravelHelper::rate_to_string($avg);
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="package-book-now-button">
            <form id="form-booking-inpage" method="post" action="" >
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="tours_add_to_cart" >
                <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID()?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="type_tour" value="<?php echo esc_html($type_tour) ?>">
                <div class="div_book">
                    <?php // $check_in = STInput::request('check_in', ''); ?>
                    <?php // $check_out = STInput::request('check_out', ''); ?>
                    <?php 
                      //  if($tour_show_calendar == 'on'):
                    ?>
                  <!--      <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                                <strong><?php// _e('Departure date',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: </strong>

                                <input placeholder ="<?php// echo __("Select a Departure Day below", ST_TEXTDOMAIN) ; ?>" id="check_in" type="text" name="check_in" value="<?php echo $check_in; ?>" readonly class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mt10">
                                <strong><?php// _e('Arrive date',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: </strong>

                                <input id="check_out" type="text" name="check_out" value="<?php // echo $check_out; ?>" readonly class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php// else: ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 mb6">
                                <a href="#list_tour_item" id="select-a-tour" class="btn btn-primary"><?php// echo __('Select a Departure Day', ST_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 mb6" style="display: none">
                                <strong><?php// _e('Departure date',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: </strong>
                                <input placeholder ="<?php //echo __("Select a day in the calendar", ST_TEXTDOMAIN) ; ?>" id="check_in" type="text" name="check_in" value="<?php echo $check_in; ?>" readonly class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 mb6" style="display: none">
                                <strong><?php // _e('Arrive date',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: </strong>
                                <input id="check_out" type="text" name="check_out" value="<?php // echo $check_out; ?>" readonly class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="list_tour_item" data-type-tour="<?php // echo $type_tour; ?>" style="display: none; width: 500px; height: auto;">
                            <div id="single-tour-calendar">
                                <?php // echo st()->load_template('tours/elements/tour_calendar'); ?>
                                <style>
                                    .qtip{
                                        max-width: 250px !important;
                                    }
                                </style>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->
                    <?php// endif; ?>
                        <div class="row mt10">
                            <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hide_adult_in_booking_form',true) != 'on'): ?>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                                <?php _e('<strong>Adults:</strong> <i>prices based on 2 people sharing</i>',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: 
                                <select class="form-control st_tour_adult" name="adult_number" required>
                                    <?php for($i = 2; $i <= 9; $i++){
                                        $is_select = '';
                                        if(STInput::request('adult_number') == $i){
                                            $is_select = 'selected="selected"';
                                        }
                                        echo  "<option {$is_select} value='{$i}'>{$i}</option>";
                                    } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hide_children_in_booking_form',true) != 'on'): ?>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <strong><?php _e('Children',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: </strong>
                                <select class="form-control st_tour_children" name="child_number" required>
                                    <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++){
                                        $is_select = '';
                                        if(STInput::request('child_number') == $i){
                                            $is_select = 'selected="selected"';
                                        }
                                        echo  "<option {$is_select} value='{$i}'>{$i}</option>";
                                    } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hide_infant_in_booking_form',true) != 'on'): ?>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <strong><?php _e('Infant',ST_TEXTDOMAIN)?>: </strong>
                                <select class="form-control st_tour_infant" name="infant_number" required>
                                    <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++){
                                        $is_select = '';
                                        if(STInput::request('infant_number') == $i){
                                            $is_select = 'selected="selected"';
                                        }
                                        echo  "<option {$is_select} value='{$i}'>{$i}</option>";
                                    } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php  $extra_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'extra_price', true); ?>
                        <?php if(is_array($extra_price) && count($extra_price)): ?>
                            <?php $extra = STInput::request("extra_price");
                            if(!empty($extra['value'])){
                                $extra_value = $extra['value'];
                            }
                            ?>

                            <label><strong><?php echo __('Cabin Upgrade', ST_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></strong></label>
                            <table class="table">
                                <?php foreach($extra_price as $key => $val): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="80%">
                                            <label for="field-<?php echo $val['extra_name']; ?>" class="ml20 mt5"><?php echo $val['title'].''; ?></label>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="extra_price[price][<?php echo $val['extra_name']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $val['extra_price']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="extra_price[title][<?php echo $val['extra_name']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $val['title']; ?>">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="20%">
                                            <select  style="width: 100px" class="form-control app" name="extra_price[value][<?php echo $val['extra_name']; ?>]" id="field-<?php echo $val['extra_name']; ?>">
                                                <?php
                                                $max_item = intval($val['extra_max_number']);
                                                if($max_item <= 0) $max_item = 1;
                                                for($i = 0; $i <= $max_item; $i++):
                                                    $check = "";
                                                    if(!empty($extra_value[$val['extra_name']]) and $i == $extra_value[$val['extra_name']]){
                                                        $check = "selected";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option <?php echo esc_html($check) ?>  value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                                <?php endfor; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </table>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="adult_price" id="adult_price">
                        <input type="hidden" name="child_price" id="child_price">
                        <input type="hidden" name="infant_price" id="infant_price">
                <!--    <div class="message_box mt10"></div> -->
                    <div class="div_btn_book_tour">
                        <?php if($st_is_booking_modal){ ?>
                            <a data-target="#tour_booking_<?php the_ID() ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-st-add-cart" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" ><?php st_the_language('book_now') ?> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></a>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                        <?php echo STTour::tour_external_booking_submit();?>                                
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php echo st()->load_template('user/html/html_add_wishlist',null,array("title"=>'','class'=>'')) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <?php 
      //  if($tour_show_calendar == 'on' && $tour_show_calendar_below == 'on'):
     ?>
     <!--<div class='tour_show_caledar_below_on'>
      <?php // echo st()->load_template('tours/elements/tour_calendar'); ?>
       </div>-->
       <?php // endif; ?>
   <?php
      if($st_is_booking_modal){?>
      <div class="mfp-with-anim mfp-dialog mfp-search-dialog mfp-hide" id="tour_booking_<?php echo get_the_ID()?>">
       <?php echo st()->load_template('tours/modal_booking');?>
   </div>

    <?php }?>
```

Comment: Which plugin is this? And how are the fields setup in the backend ? It may be that the field you are trying to remove is conditional to another or vice versa.

Comment: Its a custon one thats why its too hard to find it.. And the problem is that I cant find the guy who developed it cause he left for his country :(

Comment: Can u send me the plugin to test? I can't tell without going through the classes and seeing what is causing the headache

Comment: Thank you codiiv for your time i just made it.. I had delete the message box and there was a js error that does appear cause i delete that div. I put it back change js file and it works now... Thank you for your time really apreciate it... :D